# safety of calling restful api with id/passwd directly from a mobile application

Tags: rest, security, mobile, oauth-2.0

I'd like to add dictionary feature in my mobile app.
Oxford dictionary provides [an API](https://developer.oxforddictionaries.com/documentation/getting_started), which I can access with id/password.

Storing my access ID/password in the app doesn't look safe,
but I also want to avoid put my server between them because of the extra latency.
It seems that oauth2 is the solution for this scenario, but I have no control in the API side.
What's the common solution for this case?

Comment: But does the oxford dict API support OAuth? If not there’s not much you can do about it. Setting up a proxy server in the middle is actually good practice for this kind of use case. Not only you don’t have to expose your API key, but also you get the chance to collect analytics of user behavior (if that’s useful to you), or you can provide a cache layer that saves you some money (if cache hit, then you don’t have to pay for API request).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Oxford dict api only mentions about id / passwd access, I can't find anything about oauth support. I'll probably have to go with a proxy server & caching. Thanks a lot!